# Simple example with window.requestFileSystem() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have next problem: I try to use `window.requestFileSystem()` function in Chrome, but it failed. Look for my steps:

1)I added 'allow file access from file' flag to Chrome(see img bellow):[image]

2)I restarted the system.

3)Then I ran the Chrome with 'allow file access file' flag.

4) After all I try to launch this sample code:

```
function onInitFs(fs) {
  console.log('Opened file system: ' + fs.name);
}

    function errorHandler(e)
{
    console.log("Error");
}    
    window.requestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 5*1024*1024 /*5MB*/, onInitFs, errorHandler);
```

but It failed:
[image]

What's wrong in my actions?

Answer (score 14):

That's because this functionality is currently only availble prefixed, ie `window.webkitRequestFileSystem`

You may find this turorial interesting: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Answer (score -1):

This code works for me in chrome. I actually used it for phonegap, but I tested it first on chrome on my notebook and a yellow bar appeared on the top of the browser, asking me to allow the web app permanent storage on my local drive.

```
    navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.requestQuota(1024*1024, 
        function(grantedBytes) {
            window.requestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, grantedBytes, onInitFs, errorHandler);
        }, 
        function(errorCode) {
            alert("Storage not granted.");
        }
    );
```

Comment: 'window.webkitStorageInfo' is deprecated. Please use 'navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage' or 'navigator.webkitPersistentStorage' instead.

Answer (score -2):

open chrome from command  line using below command

```
chrome --allow-file-access-from-files
```

Answer (score -4):

You should change

```
window.requestFileSystem = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
```

to

```
window.RequestFileSystem = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
```

(The R should have been capitalized.)

Comment: Nope, the R should not have been capitalized. Only types are capitalized. Functions are written in camel case.