# FileError with Ripple emulator and getDirectory

Tags: cordova, ripple

I'm getting a FileError when attempting to create a local directory in my Phonegap application.  I am testing using the Ripple Emulator.  I have installed the [Cordova File Plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/doc/index.md).

First, I'm requesting the file system like so:

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY, 0, onFileSystemSuccess, onFileSystemFail);
```

My success handler fires:

```
function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
    console.log('fileSystem.root: ', fileSystem.root);
    var entry = fileSystem.root;
    entry.getDirectory("myDirectory", {create: true, exclusive: false}, getDirSuccess, onFileSystemFail);
}
```

That console.log reports a valid DirectoryEntry object.  But then the getDirectory error handler is called:

```
function onFileSystemFail(evt) {
    console.log("onFileSystemFail: ", evt);
}
```

Which logs the following:

> onFileSystemFail:  FileError {code: 1}

According to [the docs](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/dev/doc/index.md), this is a NOT_FOUND_ERR.  But my understanding was that the create flag will make the directory if it can't be found.

So why am I getting this FileError?

I am using:

- Phonegap 3.4.0-0.19.18
- Ripple 0.9.22
- Chrome 34.0.1847.131

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598292/is-it-able-to-test-phonegap-file-api-with-ripple-emulator?rq=1

Comment: @ConnectingCode I've tried that as well (and note that apparently window.webkitPersistentStorage is deprecated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12748920/simple-example-with-window-requestfilesystem-function/22553084#22553084). But it still doesn't work. I'm prompted in Chrome, and I grant access, but entry.getDirectory() still fails. I've also been using Chrome's --allow-file-access-from-files flag. And lastly, I'd like to be using temporary, not persistent, storage.